# Run insert outside of TRANSACTION block MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Is it possible to run a `MySQL INSERT` command outside of a `MySQL TRANSACTION`?

I would need this, because I am logging all of the errors in the database, and even if the other `MySQL` queries should be rolled back if an error occurs, the error should still be inserted in to the database.

Here's a code example:

```
<?php

DB('main')->query("START TRANSACTION;");
$error = false;
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   $rand = rand(0, 10);
   if ($rand < 5) {
       $error = true;
       DB('main')->query("INSERT INTO Errors SET ErrorText = 'There was an error'");
       break;
   }
   DB('main')->query("INSERT INTO RandomTable SET RandomValue = '" . $rand . "'");
}

if ($error) {
    DB('main')->query("ROLLBACK");
} else {
    DB('main')->query("COMMIT");
}
```

With this code, if an error occurs, the line in the `Errors` table will not be inserted at all. If I do not use `TRANSACTIONS`, I have to manually delete all lines that were inserted before an error occured.

I am aware, that I could plain and simply put the `INSERT` of the error after the `ROLLBACK` command, but imagine this, with 50 places where an error could occur, each error differing.

Comment: Short answer, yes of course. There's nothing forcing you to use transactions in the first place. Your question might be clearer if you could provide some code or additional context.

Comment: @Dave added a code example.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to store the error log in a MyISAM table, which is not affected by transactions.

Comment: @DagSondreHansen I wasn't aware of this, but I will test it, and if it really works this way, that would suit my needs perfectly!

Comment: About the suggestion of using MyISAM tables within a transaction: this is not recommended and may result in strange behavior during replication. For standard MySQL replication this will result in the MyISAM entries ending up in the binary logs _before_ the InnoDB transactions. For Galera replication this can even break your whole cluster when during a mixed transaction a rollback happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plan C:  Use a second connection to MySQL just for logging errors.

In that connection, use `autocommit=ON` without `BEGIN..COMMIT`.  That way, the 'log' records will be promptly inserted.

Comment: That is a very a good idea! Probably the best up far! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about pushing the errors in a stack and saving later?

```
DB('main')->query("START TRANSACTION;");
$error = false;
$errors = [];
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   $rand = rand(0, 10);
   if ($rand < 5) {
       $error = true;
       $errors[] = "There was an error with ".$rand;

       break;
   }
   DB('main')->query("INSERT INTO RandomTable SET RandomValue = '" . $rand . "'");
}

if ($error) {
    DB('main')->query("ROLLBACK");
    DB('main')->query("INSERT INTO Errors (ErrorText) values  (...)", $errors );
} else {
    DB('main')->query("COMMIT");
}
```